# Get memory profile data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory

How does a tool like [dotMemory](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) gather detailed data about memory usage including the number of objects in memory, their types, and their actual data?

Is it possible to retrieve this information via code in .NET, or does it require some low-level unmanaged approach?

Comment: ClrMD is a good start: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx

Answer (score 3):

dotMemory defently use [profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms404386(v=vs.110).aspx) for gathering information

Comment: Interesting, can you back your claim with a reference?

Comment: No. But i'm developer of dM ;-)

Comment: That qualifies as Yes ;)